# Why can a lambda expression return a local enum class type?

Tags: lambda, scope, c++14, type-safety, enum-class

Why and how does this work?
What type is 'auto' here?

```cpp
auto lambda = [](){
    enum class Local { X=0 };
    return Local::X;
};

auto x = lambda(); // No error! Why and what type is auto in this case?
auto y = Local::X; // Error! Of course!
```

The `enum class Local` is not known outside the lambda a type.
It's a `enum class` and therefore cannot be of type `int` without a cast, AFAIK.
How can a local type be returned as `auto` and what type is it really outside the lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why and how does this work?

It works because:

- a lambda expression causes a **unique class** to be generated and named at compile time.

  - The type of this class is named by the compiler internally.
  - Hence the compiler may come up with something like `<lambda_30560bd1c97ca682d011cd006c362574>::()::Local` for `x`.

You could obtain the lambda's type and then use that to declare objects of the type of the `enum class` contained within it:

```cpp
auto lambda = []() {
    enum class Local { X = 0, Z = 1 };
    return Local::X;
};

int main() {
    auto x = lambda(); // No error! Why and what type is auto in this case?
    //auto y = Local::X; // Error! Of course!
    using x_type = decltype(x);
    x_type y;
    y = x_type::Z; // can refer to enum members here
    y = x;
}
```

> The `enum class Local` is not known outside the lambda a type.

True, but the `enum class` is accessible if the relevant namespace is resolved. So internally `<lambda_30560bd1c97ca682d011cd006c362574>::()::Local` can resolve to `Local` inside the lambda, but it is not possible to guess this name before compilation, but we could use `decltype` or `auto` to get the type.

> It's a `enum class` and therefore cannot be of type `int` without a cast

Correct. But it still exists in the same way that an `enum class` could exist inside of a regular `class` or `struct`.

> Without a known type, how can I
>   continue work with that value outside the lambda?

The utility of this type outside of the lambda is limited. It is not an `int`, but rather has its own unique type and so it would be of little value even though it can be indirectly obtained.

Comment: You use **may** several times. Is it just a guess?
This is kind of type erasure, because without a **known type**, how can I continue work with that value outside the lambda? Is it treated e.g. a an `int` as underlying type automatically? Sorry, your answer is not satisfying.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? `using x_type = typename decltype(x);` seems not to work with GCC. ("main.cpp:10:29: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'decltype'
     using x_type = typename decltype(x);")

Comment: @cwschmidt it's just `using x_type = decltype(x);` no need for `typename`.

Comment: @yuri kilocheck I see, copied the code from the unedited answer.

Comment: @Mus campester I see, now it's plausible. Thanks.

Comment: I like `y = x_type::X;` as a demonstrative tool. Really shows that `x_type` is the enum.

Comment: The lambda part is a complete red herring.

Comment: @Mus campester Found out that is also works with private declared types in nested classes. So, **the enum class is public** seem not to matter...

    `class A {
        auto GetPrivateB() {
            struct B{};
            return B{};
        }
    public:
        auto GetPublicB() {
            return GetPrivateB();
        }
    };

    int main() {
        A a;
       auto x = a.GetPublicB();
    }`

Comment: @T.C. Fair enough. Everything is compile time determined.

Comment: @cwschmidt You might have a point, but I don't see a lambda in your example. It looks like a public function is calling a private one in a regular named class.

Comment: @Mus campester My point (of interest) was not the lambda per se, but the hidden inner type (which I occasionally/coincidentally declared within a lambda (which came into my min first). But as @yuri kilochek already stated, the same situation can be created by e.g. nested struct or now classes. So for my original interest the lambda was not the 'red herring', but the **inner type** and `auto` at the outside.

Comment: @Mus campester Yes, public method calls private method, which declares the type inside. This shows that types are always kind of public disregarding the private section opposed to a lambda which the compiler of course translates somehow into a `struct` with `operator()` overwritten where everything is public.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with lambdas or `enum class`es, this works for any local type in any function with deduced return type:

```
auto f() {
    struct X {};
    return X{};
}

int main() {
    auto x = f();
}
```

Type of `x` cannot be directly referred to from outside function scope, but it is indeed `X` defined within `f`.